# Show that there are two 5-element subsets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have such question and I don not know how to handle it.

## Task

$A\subset \left \{ 1,..., 50 \right \}, |A|=10$   . Show that there are two 5-element subsets of A with the same sum of elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximal sum a 5 element subset of $A$ could possible have, is $50+49+48+47+46 = 240$, the minimal sum is $1+2+3+4+5=15$ so there are *at most* $226$ possible sums. Now there are $\binom{10}{5} = 252$ different 5-element subsets of $A$. By the pigeon hole principle there must be two such subset that have the same sum.

Answer (score 3):

How many such subsets are there?

How many possible values do you have for the sum of the elements?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/940153)

Comment: That was a hint leading straight to the answer. It is commonplace on MSE.

Comment: [You're right.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10589/290189)  Excuse me for this failed review.  Failed reviews are also common on Math.SE.

Comment: It's alright :) Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Use the pigeon hole principle. There are ${10\choose{5}} = 252$ subsets of $A$ of size $5$. Each of these has some sum that lies in the set $S=\{15, 16,\dots 240\}$. The limits for this set $S$ come from the fact that the minimal sum is $1+2+3+4+5=15$ and the maximal sum $46+47+48+49+50=240$. So there are only $226$ possible values for the sum. That means there must be two subsets of $A$ of size $5$ that have the same sum.